# z transform adding terms linearity

Tags: z-transform

i am very sorry as this is an easy question but my confidence is very low. in a text book the author has the following signal and z transform.
the signal is,
$$f(n) = 2u(n) + 3u(n)$$
the author then goes on to give the z transform as,
$$F(z) = 2\frac{z}{z-1} + 3\frac{z}{z-1}$$

surely the signal can be given as
$$f(n) = 5u(n)$$

and the transform as
$$F(z) = 5\frac{z}{z-1}$$

did i miss something? very sorry but my confidence is so low and i dont get why the author would leave it like this if not for some specific reason that i have missed

Comment: Everything is correct. If both step functions happen at the same time, their transforms are equal and therefore their sum is valid on both time and frequency domain